# Sphere in an Electric Field: Why Constant is Zero?

Tags: electrostatics, potential, voltage, conventions

In Example 3.8 of *Introduction to Electrodynamics*, Griffiths places an uncharged metal sphere of radius $R$ in a uniform electric field $\textbf{E} = E_0 \hat{z}$.

[image]

For distance $r\gg R$, a potential function for $\textbf{E}$ is given by
$$
V = - E_0 \, z + C,
$$
where $R$ is the radius of the sphere and, $C$ is the integration constant.

Griffiths argues that $C = 0$ because

> $V = 0$ in the equatorial plane.

This argument is not clear to me.

Is it possible to prove it in any other way? Equivalently, can you please explain this to me?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me that Griffiths defines the voltage to be $0$ when $z = 0$, which is why we have $C = 0$.

It’s difficult to talk about *the* potential at a certain point because of that integration constant. So, we usually pick and agree on a reference point. In this case, the reference point is $V = 0$ when $z = 0$. Another example is taking the gravitational potential energy to be $0$ when $r = \infty$.

Answer (score 3):

The answer above is accurate but doesn't emphasize the key point. Voltage differences are well-defined, but absolute voltage is not. If I have a simple circuit with a 1.5V battery with a 1 ohm resistor connected across it, is the + terminal of the battery at +1.5 V, or is the - terminal at -1.5 V? Suppose I place the whole thing into a spherical conducting shell which is at 1,000 V; does that change the answers?.
 No, it doesn't, because absolute voltage is not defined. In the problem, choosing V = 0 on the equatorial plane is mathematically convenient but is an arbitrary choice. You may recall the voltage is the integral of the electric field, but as in any integral there is an arbitrary constant of integration.

Answer (score 2):

To add a minor correction to the previous answers, Griffiths does not define the xy plane to have $0$ potential. Instead, he defines the conducting sphere, which is equipotential (since there can be no electric field inside a conductor in electrostatics) to have $V=0$. Hence we see that at least the portion of the xy plane within the sphere has $V=0$. The question now is how do we generalize this to the $\textbf{entire}$ xy plane?

The induced charge in the metallic sphere distort the original electric field so that the final field is not $\mathbf{E} = E_0\mathbf{\hat{z}}$, but rather $\mathbf{E} = E_0\mathbf{\hat{z}} + \mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{distortion}}$ where $\mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{distortion}}$ is the field caused by the induced charge in the sphere. In the xy plane, $\mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{distortion}}$ cannot have any component in the x or y direction, because by the symmetry of the problem there needs to be exactly as much positive charge in the northern hemisphere as there is negative charge in the southern hemisphere (both being distributed in the same way), such that any contribution to the x and y components of  $\mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{distortion}}$ made by the positive charges will be cancelled out by the negative charges. Hence $\mathbf{E}_{\mathrm{distortion}}$ and therefore $\mathbf{E}$ itself will have no x or y component in the xy plane. You can see this in the illustration given by Griffiths that you have included, where the field goes straight upwards where it crosses the xy plane.

If you remember $\Delta V = -\int \mathbf{E} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{l}$, if we start in a portion of the xy plane within the sphere (where $V=0$) and go to anywhere else on the xy plane, $\mathbf{E} \cdot \mathrm{d}\mathbf{l} = 0$ since $\mathbf{E}$ only has a z component and $\mathrm{d}\mathbf{l}$ only has x and y components. Therefore $ V=0$ for the entire xy plane, necessitating that $C=0$ for $z=0$.

Answer (score 0):

Indeed, only the potential difference makes sense. And usually, we take the zero potential to infinity.

But, as the radius of the earth, globally neutral, is very large compared to other everyday objects, it can be proved that if we connect a conductor to the earth via a voltage generator $E$, the potential of the conductor with respect to infinity is practically equal to $E$ and that of the earth is much less than $E$.

It is therefore reasonable to speak of zero potential for a grounding.